# Checking for 'input' and 'select' jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a script which generates textboxes and dropdown-lists dynamically.

```
var ss = $('#ss');
$('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
    $('#ss').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillItem", "Item")', // dont hard code your url's
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { MnId: $('#MainGrpId').val(), SbId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
        success: function (y) {
            alert("Im in");
            $.each(y, function (l, u) {
                // add the label
                var label = u.Name;
                var name = 'Field' + l;
                var label = $('<label></label>').text(label).attr('for', name);
                ss.append(label);
                if (u.Options.length==0) {
                    // There is only one item and its for generating a textbox
                        var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name });
                    ss.append(input);
                } else {
                    // Its a select
                    var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });
                    // add each option
                    $.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
                        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text));
                    })
                    ss.append(select);
                }
            });
            var labelAdd = $("<label id='lblId'>").text('Refresh');
            ss.append(labelAdd);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

View briefly

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Item"))
{
   <div id="ss" class="col-md-6">

   </div>

   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.ItemName, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = " Item Name", TextMode = "MultiLine2", onkeyup = "return validateChar(this)", style = "width:175px;height:25px;" })

   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" /> 
}
```

Now i want to get the text in texboxes and selected item's text of ddls to 'ItemName' textbox seperated by spaces. When user starts entering to a textbox, text should start getting binded to 'ItemName' textbox. If user selects an item from a ddl, let's say "itemThree" then that text should get added separated by a space to the textbox. This is what i have done.

```
$('#ss').on( function () {
    if ($('#Field0').is('input')) {
        var f1 = $('#Field0').val();
    }
    else {
        var f1 = $('#Field0 option:selected').text();
    }

    if ($('#Field1').is('input')) {
        var f2 = $('#Field1').val();
    }
    else {
        var f2 = $('#Field1 option:selected').text();
    }
    ....
        $('#ItemName').val(f1 +" "+ f2 +" "+ f3....);

});
```

But this script is not working. This doesn't bind texts of textboxes and selected item text of ddls to 'ItemName' textbox. 
I worte the above script in that way because as an example id ('Field1') can be a textbox or ddl.
So i checked for both situations. Could anyone pls help me with this. Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to follow, can you re-phrase your issue?

Comment: @ DelightedD0D, ok.. The first script is not that much necessary for this. Consider the last script. There are dynamically generated textboxes and ddls. Sequence of them is not relevant. If user starts entering a text to a textbox It should be start getting displayed in 'ItemName'  textbox. If user selects an item from a ddl then the text associated with that item should get displayed in textbox. Now it's like this "textboxtext ddlitemone .... ...."

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle using the **generated HTML**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are having is, binding the event handlers to the changes in the textbox or the changes in the dropdown (select).

Here's what you need to do:

1.First, add a Class name for the dynamically created textbox and dropdown controls as follows (the only change is the addition of the class attribute, this is used for the selector in the buildValues function)

```
var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name, class:"field" });
var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name, class:"field" });
```

2.Next, just after you have appended everything to the ss, you need to add the event handlers as follows, where buildValues is the event handler.

```
var labelAdd = $("<label id='lblId'>").text('Refresh');
ss.append(labelAdd);
$(".field").on("change", buildValues);
```

3.Finally, here's the event handler that will build the values as per your requirements:

```
function buildValues(){
var txtValues = [];
$("input.field").each(function(){
txtValues.push($(this).val());
});
$("select.field").each(function(){
txtValues.push($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});

$("#ItemName").val(txtValues.join(" "));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear solution :) sorry for the late reply(due to a power failure). This works fine with ddls. But for textboxes it only works for the first textbox. texts in other textboxes are not getting binded with "ItemName" textbox. Is there something i have to do extra? pls help

Comment: Good news. Plead could you accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: yes sure im going to. But could you pls help me to get this script work correctly?

Comment: I have updated the code based on the fact that there could be multiple textboxes.

Comment: Thank you.. Yes now it is working perfectly. I had to change the script like this " $('#ss').on('change keyup', '.field', function ()....." since these html elements are dynamically created and have to bind to a already existing div. If you could pls make that change in your script. That would be useful for others... Thanks again..